# New user password confirmation sending wrong URL

Tags: login, password

We use the itheme security to hide the back end of our site. 
When a user signs up they receive an email that says:

To set your password, visit the following address:

https://www.ecample.co.uk/wp-login.php?action=rp&key=abcdefg12345&login=user%40example.com

This doesn't add the hide back end key so users are being taken to a "this page is disabled" screen.

Could someone please tell me where I can edit the text of this email to add the necessary key?

Answer (score 0):

The link of the password reset mail is set [here](https://github.com/xwp/wordpress-develop/blob/master/src/wp-login.php#L390). To adjust the link you have two possibilities. Either use the `retrieve_password_message` filter or use the filter from the [`network_site_url()`](https://github.com/xwp/wordpress-develop/blob/master/src/wp-includes/link-template.php#L3361) function call. When using the `retrieve_password_message` filter you would have to probably use a regex to match for the url to add your additional parameters or create a whole new text message.

I'd rather recommend using the [`network_site_url`](https://github.com/xwp/wordpress-develop/blob/master/src/wp-includes/link-template.php#L3389) filter and add your parameters to the URL there. As this filter will apply globally you would have to add conditionals if you want to limit it for specific URLs.